# train Word2vec model using Gensim

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

this is my code.it reads reviews from an excel file (rev column) and make a list of list.

xp is like this

```
["['intrepid', 'bumbling', 'duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one'],['better', 'offering', 'considerable', 'cv', 'freshly', 'qualified', 'private', 'investigator', 'thrust', 'murder', 'investigation', 'invisible'],[ 'man', 'alone', 'tell', 'fun', 'flow', 'decent', 'clip', 'need', 'say', 'sequence', 'comedy', 'gold', 'like', 'scene', 'restaurant', 'excellent', 'costello', 'pretending', 'work', 'ball', 'gym', 'final', 'reel']"]
```

but when use list for model, it gives me error"TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable".i don't know where is my problem.
Thanks.

```
xp=[]
import gensim 
import logging
import pandas as pd 
file = r'FileNamelast.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='FileNamex')
pages = [i for i in range(0,1000)]


for page in  pages:

 text =df.loc[page,["rev"]]
 xp.append(text[0])


model = gensim.models.Word2Vec (xp, size=150, window=10, min_count=2, 
workers=10)
model.train(xp,total_examples=len(xp),epochs=10)
```

this is what i got.TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-aa34c0e432bf> in <module>()
     14 
     15 
---> 16 model = gensim.models.Word2Vec (xp, size=150, window=10, min_count=2, workers=10)
     17 model.train(xp,total_examples=len(xp),epochs=10)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py in __init__(self, sentences, corpus_file, size, alpha, window, min_count, max_vocab_size, sample, seed, workers, min_alpha, sg, hs, negative, ns_exponent, cbow_mean, hashfxn, iter, null_word, trim_rule, sorted_vocab, batch_words, compute_loss, callbacks, max_final_vocab)
    765             callbacks=callbacks, batch_words=batch_words, trim_rule=trim_rule, sg=sg, alpha=alpha, window=window,
    766             seed=seed, hs=hs, negative=negative, cbow_mean=cbow_mean, min_alpha=min_alpha, compute_loss=compute_loss,
--> 767             fast_version=FAST_VERSION)
    768 
    769     def _do_train_epoch(self, corpus_file, thread_id, offset, cython_vocab, thread_private_mem, cur_epoch,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py in __init__(self, sentences, corpus_file, workers, vector_size, epochs, callbacks, batch_words, trim_rule, sg, alpha, window, seed, hs, negative, ns_exponent, cbow_mean, min_alpha, compute_loss, fast_version, **kwargs)
    757                 raise TypeError("You can't pass a generator as the sentences argument. Try an iterator.")
    758 
--> 759             self.build_vocab(sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, trim_rule=trim_rule)
    760             self.train(
    761                 sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, total_examples=self.corpus_count,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py in build_vocab(self, sentences, corpus_file, update, progress_per, keep_raw_vocab, trim_rule, **kwargs)
    934         """
    935         total_words, corpus_count = self.vocabulary.scan_vocab(
--> 936             sentences=sentences, corpus_file=corpus_file, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)
    937         self.corpus_count = corpus_count
    938         self.corpus_total_words = total_words

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py in scan_vocab(self, sentences, corpus_file, progress_per, workers, trim_rule)
   1569             sentences = LineSentence(corpus_file)
   1570 
-> 1571         total_words, corpus_count = self._scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per, trim_rule)
   1572 
   1573         logger.info(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py in _scan_vocab(self, sentences, progress_per, trim_rule)
   1552                     sentence_no, total_words, len(vocab)
   1553                 )
-> 1554             for word in sentence:
   1555                 vocab[word] += 1
   1556             total_words += len(sentence)

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You pass the wrong value to gensim. "You can't pass a generator as the sentences argument. Try an iterator.".

Comment: An example of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sentences` corpus argument to `Word2Vec` should be an iterable sequence of lists-of-word-tokens.

Your reported value for `xp` is actually a list with one long string in it:

```py
[
  "['intrepid', 'bumbling', 'duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one'],['better', 'offering', 'considerable', 'cv', 'freshly', 'qualified', 'private', 'investigator', 'thrust', 'murder', 'investigation', 'invisible'],[ 'man', 'alone', 'tell', 'fun', 'flow', 'decent', 'clip', 'need', 'say', 'sequence', 'comedy', 'gold', 'like', 'scene', 'restaurant', 'excellent', 'costello', 'pretending', 'work', 'ball', 'gym', 'final', 'reel']"
]
```

I don't see how this would give the error you've reported, but it's definitely wrong, so should be fixed. You should perhaps print `xp` just before you instantiate `Word2Vec` to be sure you know what it contains.

A true list, with each item being a list-of-string-tokens, would work. So if `xp` were the following that'd be correct:

```py
    [
      ['intrepid', 'bumbling', 'duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one'],
      ['better', 'offering', 'considerable', 'cv', 'freshly', 'qualified', 'private', 'investigator', 'thrust', 'murder', 'investigation', 'invisible'],
      [ 'man', 'alone', 'tell', 'fun', 'flow', 'decent', 'clip', 'need', 'say', 'sequence', 'comedy', 'gold', 'like', 'scene', 'restaurant', 'excellent', 'costello', 'pretending', 'work', 'ball', 'gym', 'final', 'reel']
    ]
```

Note, however:

- `Word2Vec` doesn't do well with toy-sized datasets. So while this tiny setup may be helpful to check for basic syntax/format issues, don't expect realistic results until you're training with many hundreds-of-thousands of words.
- You don't need to call `train()` if you already supplied your corpus at instantiation, as you have. The model will do all steps automatically. (If, on the other hand, you don't supply your corpus, you'd then have to call *both* `build_vocab()` and `train()`.) If you enable logging at the INFO level all the steps happening behind the scenes will be clearer.

Comment: i solve the problem.but there is a problem .my file is 150 Mg and i don't know how to feed it to word2vec because it gives me insufficient RAM error.

Comment: If you're already hitting memory problems with just 150MB of data, you may need to work on a machine with more RAM. However, you don't need to bring your full dataset into memory: gensim models are designed to work with iterable sequences, so they can train as data is incrementally read from disk. Many examples in gensim docs/tutorials show how to read data that way. Still, if you're using `min_count=2`, you may be retaining so many words your model won't fit in memory. You'd have to post more info about what you've tried, and how it's failed, probably as a new question, for more help.